ESP32 with MQ+35 and anemometer malfunctioning
I am building a weatherstation for a schoolproject.
The weatherstation is powered by an ESP32 with a bmp280+aht20, mq135 and an anemometer.
Sadly the mq135 and anemometer dont seem to work quite right or give me correct values.
My connections are like that:
The ESP32: ESP32 D1 mini
MQ135: GND, 5V and GPIO34
Anemometer: GND and GPIO35
thats my code for the anemomet and the mq135
the anemometer is just constantly giving the adc value 0
const int MQ135 = 34;
int sensorState = 0;

const int anemometerPin = 35; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
 analogReadResolution(12);
  analogSetAttenuation(ADC_0db); 

pinMode(MQ135 , INPUT); pinMode(anemometerPin , INPUT); 
}

float readWindspeed() {
  int adcValue = analogRead(anemometerPin);
  Serial.println(adcValue);

  return adcValue;
}

float readAirquality() {

  const float Vcc = 5.0;

  int sensorValue = analogRead(MQ135);
  
  float Rs = (sensorValue / 1023.0) * Vcc;

  Serial.println(sensorValue);

  // CO₂-Konzentration berechnen
  float ppm = pow((Rs/76.63),0.3611)*146.15;
  Serial.println(ppm);
  Serial.print("CO2 Concentration: ");
  Serial.print(ppm);
  Serial.println(" ppm");

  return ppm;
}


Also the conversion between the ADC value to CO2 PPM (with the mq135) seems to give me a wrong value...
Thank you so much for any help!

You set ADC resolution to 12 bit with analogReadResolution(12);, yet your conversion from reading to Rs is using 10-bit (1023) instead of 12-bit (4095).

If you have an ESP32, The supply voltage TO ESP32 is 3.3v, not 5.0v that you used in VCC.
